# Filling gridview on button click, no database selected error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to populate a grid view on button click using text box data in the select statement. Below is the error I receive when clicking the button event. I have tried to play around with the code to no avail. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myConnection = "datasource=blahblah;port=blahblah;username=blahblah;password=blahblah";
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM purchase_history_table WHERE student_id LIKE   '%" + this.TextBoxstudentid.Text + "%' ;", con);
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(dt1);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: do not post links to an Image post actual Code.. also posting an error is not enough information show us the code.. is a good starting point

Comment: You missed `Initial Catalog` in connection string

Comment: take a look at this link on how to configure [C# ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com] select the MySql link once you navigate to the site.. also to take advantage of the `Auto Disposing` of your created Sql Objects, wrap your code around a `using(){}` statement

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this concept, as described below.  This works fine for me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Globalization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = CsvFileToDatatable(@"C:\Users\xxx\test.csv", false);
        }


        public DataTable CsvFileToDatatable(string path, bool IsFirstRowHeader) //here Path is root of file and IsFirstRowHeader is header is there or not
        {
            string header = "No";
            string sql = string.Empty;
            DataTable dataTable = null;
            string pathOnly = string.Empty;
            string fileName = string.Empty;

            try
            {

                pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

                sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";

                if (IsFirstRowHeader)
                {
                    header = "Yes";
                }

                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
                        @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
                        ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
                        {
                            dataTable = new DataTable();
                            dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                            adapter.Fill(dataTable);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {

            }

            return dataTable;

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```